# admob native ads will be shown?

Tags: android, admob

i have been trying to implement Native Ads from admob.

I got some sample code from Github. I tried to implement this code, and the demo code works fine. The native ads show up properly.

I then created my own Admob account and obtained an Ad Unit ID. The previous demo code for native ad did not work with this id, and I got an error with error code 0 although my created Ad Unit ID works fine for banner type ads.

Are this native ads still in beta?? when are they supposed to be out for the common developer?

Comment: Search for Firebase Advanced Native Ads Android. you will find link of my blog site (developine). it has all details.

Answer (score 3):

Helllom I have the same problem but I dont think the real problem be the space. I'm not sure but maybe Native Ads Advanced are still in beta. I try the same code with the Ad Unit ID from admob's example and it works fine. You can try the examples code with your ad units but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: That's correct. As for August 2017, they still are in closed beta.

Answer (score 1):

What happens to me every time I create an Admob banner ad, it takes a while to appear. So i think you should check again in an hour. I'm guessing Google is processing ad unit id and this is taking some time.

Also, they're not in beta. You should be able to use them. If you still cannot see real ads, post your code and I'll take a look at it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I actually set this native ad two days ago, and if i set adapterWrapper.setTestDeviceId("6E8E64F2C8A5F89FCB197C595E233562"); i can see ads, but if i dont set this... no ad is being served. Im also using admobadapter to set ads inbetween listview items (https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter)

Comment: do i need to use Firebase ? should i integrate firebase sdk?

Comment: No, I'm not using Firebase and my ads are working properly. So you are trying to display the ads in a listview if I understood it correctly. In my opinion the ads are not appearing because the space that you provided is not enough. According to Google if there isn't enough space no ad will be shown. That's what happened to me when I tried to make the adview smaller. So I'm guessing this is your issue.

Comment: Have you tried putting ads in a regular adview in relative layout just to see if the ads appear?

Comment: im gonna try that and let you know.

Comment: Berat, just a quick question, when you try and didn't have enough space (whatever that means) did you still get ads when using test device? or you didnt even get test ads? because its really weird for me that using test device i'm able to see ads and when i take that i dont see any ad

Comment: I don't remember what happened when tried to squeeze test ads in a smaller space. In my opinion live ad sizes vary that's why sometimes it may not show up. Have you tried basic Google adview in your app?

Comment: the thing is that i have a listview and very little knowledge of android... but i found this avocarrot ad network that was really easy to implement... so i guess i will try with them until i'm able to master android listviews/adapters, thanks anyway for your patience buddy!

Comment: Please tell me,  android native ads work only on devices with testDeviceId, or after I'm deploy it in play store it will be work on all user devices?  In my case it work only if device added to setTestDeviceId. And I'm not understand, it feature or bug

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you meant exactly but when you add native ads to your app they will be shown regardless of they are test ads or live ads. So you can show both test and live ads when your users use the app.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the exact same error. I implemented native ad code from the example given in git hub. Now I am always getting error code '0' .

Funny thing . When I replace My ad unit Id with the ad_unit_id given in Example.

Ads is displaying in my APP. So it is Clear that my implementation is  Correct.

There is some problem with admob ad unit. Its been 18 hour since I created it, I am still getting error with my ad_unit. 
If it is ad_unit activation problem then , How would I know it is ready or not , or  i have to create some other new ad_unit.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. This does not answer OP's question.