# AdMob Native ads not shown

Tags: android, admob, ads

I implemented a new AdMob Native Ads for Android, but it work only if I adding device id into `AdRequest.addTestDevice()`

After loading I have a next `LogCat` stack:

> I: Starting ad request.
>
> I: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("241E542ADB6B0EDC7765DAAC7107523B") to get test ads on this device.
>
> W: Received error HTTP response code: 403
>
> W: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
>
> W: Failed to load ad: 0

I tried different network(VPN) and different devices.
AdMob placement was created 25 hours ago.

I tried use google sample app id, placement id and google-services.json and all work fine, but with real data I have only error

I found [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514926/admob-native-ads-will-be-shown) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934671/admob-native-ads-in-recyclerview) , but did not get an answer whether it will work after I deploy application in Google Play?

Comment: Same problem here. Even after publishing in the play store. I used this doc: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/native#system-defined_native_ad_formats

Comment: I discovered that for native advertising necessary to get permission from AdMob as this format is in the beta test

Answer (score 1):

I´m not sure why, I couldn´t find any info about that, but if you change in your google-services.json

```
"ads_service": {
  "status": 2
}
```

to

```
"ads_service": {
  "status": 1
 }
```

your native adds will appear.
This only happens with native, the regular banner is displayed even with status 2.

EDIT:
This solution stopped working in my app.

Comment: Only AdMob approved users can use native (Install and Content) ads in application. For more information please write to AdMob support.